# Run a python script from another script IN Parallel with arguments

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to run a python script from another script and pass variables to it. I'm able to do it using -

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("python C:\\Users\\Dev\\Desktop\\second.py hi hello how")
```

Note - Hi, Hello and How are my arguments to my second script

second.py:

```
import sys
a = sys.argv[1]
b = sys.argv[2]
c = sys.argv[3]
print (a)
print (b)
print (c)
```

What i observed here that when i call the second script from the first one, the first script is waiting until the second script completes its execution.

**But i want them to be executed as a separate script i.e. first script should just call the second script and then continue with its tasks rather than waiting for second script to complete**.

I've tried using the below for this approach -

```
import threading, os
from subprocess import call   
ipath = "C:\\Users\\Dev\\Desktop\\second.py"
def thread_second():
    call(["python", ipath])
processThread = threading.Thread(target=thread_second)  
processThread.start()
```

But for this method using threading, I'm unable to pass arguments but this is working like I expect, execute as two different scripts.

How can I make my script work in a way where the first script should just call the second script and then continue with its tasks rather than waiting for second script to complete and should also be taking arguments.

I've seen various posts on this question but couldn't find the right to satisfy this condition.

I am just confused how you do it.

Comment: why are you unable to pass the arguments ? just add more elements to the list inside `call(["python", ipath])` ?

Comment: I tried, i see the error - **Errno 2: No such file or directory**. `ipath = "C:\\Users\\Dev\\Desktop\\second.py hi hello how"`, is this the right way ?

Comment: Not like that add it inside the call  function like `call(["python", ipath,"hi", "hello","how" ])`

Comment: And keep the Ipath the same as in your code

Comment: Perfect, this worked! thanks for that